# Can I supply sectors with strategic resources?

Tags: stellaris

I had a couple of Betharian power plants on planets within my empire. I recently reached my core planets limit so I created a new sector, the Betharian resource is no longer being supplied to those power plants and now I'm loosing energy due to the lack of them being powered.

Can I give my Betharian resource to sectors, or do I need to remove the planet from the sector so that Betharian power plants can be supplied by me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a system with the resource to the sector in order for the sector to have access to it. Your core planets have access to any resource in your core sector, which is all the systems not in a sector.

So, in your specific situation, you can either remove the system from the sector so that both it and a system supplying the resource are in your core sector, or you need to add a system supplying the resource to the same sector as the system trying to consume the resource.

Comment: Any strategic resource in a sector that is not used in that sector, will fully spill over to your core sector. This is different than how minerals are handled.

Comment: @Sjoerd I'll watch out for that.