# What's the best way to create a new Sector in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

What are the dos and don'ts of new Sector creation?

**The story:**

Our empire expanded greatly in the last few decades and reached its limit.
We need to create our first sector.

We need your tips as an experienced empire ruler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wesex Commonality Salute you Commander, to create a sector within an empire, you must enter the planets menu on your HUB. Once an overview of planets can be seen, scrolling to the bottom of the list will reveal the "Create a new sector" option. Once the option has been selected, you must designate a starting planet that has been colonized successfully, once done, you may expand by selecting near planets which will increase the borders of a sector and allow you to designate resources that sector has access too.

Once a sector has been created, going back to the planets menu and scrolling down to the sector you have just created, will allow you to designate their focus, whether it be Science, Mineral, Military and Credit based focus. You will also see an option to change their taxes to you, it is recommended at first you provide them with either 0%/25% taxes to allow them to expand their facilities on planet which in turn will allow you to gain more resources later on as you raise the taxes.

It is also important to note you can dictate policies of building replacement and respecting tile resources to make sure your new sector will not overwrite current resources to create new ones based on your focus.

Good luck to you Commander,

we will be watching.

Comment: We thank the 'Wesex Commonality' for sharing their experience (LOL). 
Any other tips, e.g. we found that adding solar systems (logically) reducing our empire resources (again - logically, after doing so and thinking about it :-) ).

Comment: +1, should probably point out what happens when you add additional systems that don't have colonies. As ShloEmi pointed out, those resources go to the sector. Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/266142/108003